# shared files or folders being locked by administrator

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share, file-sharing

I have a user who uses a share folder. the folders are in 2003 windows server.

she started to complain about files and folders which she cannot rename or move.

I checked the open files under Shared Folders in computer management and the folders and files she uses at the time are opened by administrator not by her. but only she uses those files no one else using the files or folders.

She has windows 7.

I have to close those files from computer management in server 2003 all the time for her to rename or move the files.

why do you think this is happening?

Comment: real-time AV scanning in use on the server, like McAfee?  I've seen it cause these types of situations.

Comment: Possibly a AV service running or some other type of indexer?

Comment: As well as AV scanning, this can also be caused by the explorer.exe process on a client trying to index files or trying to build a `thumbs.db` file, it often happens if the directory contains images, pdf files etc. Does the computer management open files give any clues as to what files / directories are locked?

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). And run it on the server

```
1. Click Find menu 
2. "Find Handle or DLL"
3. Enter file name or path
```

You will get a list of processes that have the file or folder(s) open. This can help you to determine what happens.

Answer (score 0):

An app like [PA File Sight](http://www.poweradmin.com/file-sight) would let you track access to those files and find out what IP address the administrator account is accessing them from.  And if access is coming from the server itself, it would tell you what process was the source of the access.